# Jekyll - Highlighter on Aviator Theme?

Tags: jekyll

Im unsure which highlighting system is being used on: https://github.com/CloudCannon/Aviator-Jekyll-Theme

It uses code like:

````
``` json
[
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "The Hunger Games",
  "score": 4.5,
  "dateAdded": "12/12/2013"
},
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "The Hunger Games",
  "score": 4.7,
  "dateAdded": "15/12/2013"
},
]
```
````

But code like:

````
``` c++
```
````

Doesnt seem to work.
Cant find any CSS or JS references to anything so its confusing me heavily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aviator uses the default Jekyll syntax highlighter - [Rouge](http://rouge.jneen.net/). I haven't tried this but if you use cpp instead of c++ it might work.

Comment: Ill give it a go - But where did you find this out? Lets say I want to swap to a different highlighter - How would I?

Comment: I made the theme :-). It's also the default used by Jekyll. You could switch to a JavaScript based solution instead of doing in Jekyll.

Comment: Oh wow, Nice - Any chance you could tell me a way to make the Code Window show a vertical scrollbar if it goes too long compared to the text. Heres a good example: https://imreallyshiny.github.io/modtools/#tutorials5_zombie_counter

Comment: Just put a max height on it.

Comment: How? Like since we are doing the ``` thing there's no way to add style="" etc to it

Comment: You can add it to the css file. Something like:

code { max-height: 300px; }